# O problema [object HTMLInputElement] aparece em um function em JS

Tags: javascript, html

Estou começando na área do html, então venho aqui perguntar sobre um problema decorrent em meu código: eu criei um input de tipo text (onde a pessoa ira por seu nome), e para o nome da pessoa aparecer na minha pagina, eu usei um input de tipo boton para ela confirmar seu nome, onde na area de script criei uma function para ativar o texto do nome no html, mas há um decorrente problema em relação com o [object HTMLInputElement], e venho auqi pedir a ajuda de alguns especialistas, obrigado pela atenção.
AQUI ESTÁ O CÓDIGO:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculadora_avanced</title>
    <style>
        body{
            background-color: yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Olá!</h1>
    <div style="text-align: ;"><input type="text" id="usuarioname" name="usuarioname" value="Qual seu nome?" >
    <input type="button" id="entername" value="confirmar" onclick="entername()">
    </div>
    <div id="nemers" style="text-align: ;"></div>
    <script>
        function entername() {
            var namers = window.document.getElementById('nemers')
            var na = window.document.getElementById('usuarioname')
            namers.innerText = `Olá ${na} , como vai?`

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bom dia. [Edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/479362/edit) sua pergunta para adicionar mais detalhes e esclarecimentos a respeito do problema apresentado, para que possamos responder sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

O Elemento `input[type=text]` precisa ter o atributo `value` acessado para você conseguir exibir o valor digitado no mesmo.

Altere seu código para:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculadora_avanced</title>
    <style>
        body{
            background-color: yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Olá!</h1>
    <div style="text-align: ;"><input type="text" id="usuarioname" name="usuarioname" value="Qual seu nome?" >
    <input type="button" id="entername" value="confirmar" onclick="entername()">
    </div>
    <div id="nemers" style="text-align: ;"></div>
    <script>
        function entername() {
            var namers = window.document.getElementById('nemers')
            var na = window.document.getElementById('usuarioname')
            namers.innerText = `Olá ${na.value} , como vai?`

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Se você usar a função `console.log(na)` e visualizar no Console do Navegador, vai ver que vai ser retornado o `input`.

O Javascript converte o objeto para o nome do mesmo quando você tenta utilizá-lo como string, o que gerou o "[object HtmlInputElement]" no seu código.

Utilize o atributo `value` sempre que quiser acessar/alterar o valor do input do seu HTML através do Javascript.

Mais informações na documentação da [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)

Comment: muito obrigado rapaz